# Custom Windows USB / RNDIS .inf file to change Network Connections Name

Tags: windows, driver, inf, network-connection, rndis

I have have my embedded Linux device communicating with Windows 7 via Ethernet over USB using the `g_ether` driver in Linux. I am attempting to modify the example `linux.inf` file in the kernel source under `src/Documentation/usb/` in order to have my device appear in the Windows Network Connections Dialog box as something other than 'Local Area Connection 2'.

I have simply modified the `[strings]` portion of the `linux.inf` file to specifiy a custom string that does appear as a substring under the 'Local Area Connection 2' main title.

I don't know how to get my device to say for instance 'Phils Device' instead of 'Local Area Connection 2'. I would greatly appreciate if somebody could enlighten me on how to do this! Thanks -

Portion of example .inf file I modified:

```
[Strings]
Company               = "Phil"
CompanyDevice         = "Phils Device"
Vista_Property        = "Phils Device"
ServiceDisplayName    = "Phils Device Driver"
```

References:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff570620.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463293.aspx